# In Grails, how to allow newer DNS in email validator constraint?

Tags: validation, email, grails, dns, constraints

```
static constraints = {
    email email:true
}
```

This constraint treats test@email.wtf as invalid. How to allow newer DNS like '.wtf' as valid email?

I could create a *CustomEmailValidator* extending `org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator`, then using a class similar to `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.routines.DomainValidator` with the additional DNS.

But is there any simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with not matching the new domains specifically, you could just relax email rules to something like this:

```
static constraints = {
  email(matches: '^\\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,63}$')
}
```